# Connection string for ms Access in Ms winforms application

Tags: winforms, ms-access

Everything is perfect in this connection string according to my knowledge.But its not working fine.I'll be very thankful if someone helps me out to sort out this issue.Thanks

```
   string constr = "**Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Data Source=F:/Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False**"; 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr);
```

---

Comment: Data Source=Data Source=F:/Database1.accdb  <=  Data Source=F:\Database1.accdb

Comment: still its not working... "F:\" is throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current connection string has multiple issues. Try this instead:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Comment: still it is giving error.." microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine c#".. i have installed it but still its giving same error..

Comment: @user2927881 It sounds like the version you installed does not match the "bitness" of your application. For example, if you are running a 64-bit application then you need the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine.

Comment: "64-bit version of the Access Database Engine" was missing..i have installed it but now when i try to add its .DLL . Error is poping up and system is not letting me to add this refrence.how it can be sorted out???

Comment: On 64-bit versions of Windows look for the below paths:

64-bit - "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL"         i am trying to add this refrence..but its giving error...

Comment: @user2927881 You don't need to add a Reference to your project in order to use a particular OLEDB driver. You just create an `OleDbConnection` object that includes the appropriate name in the `Provider=` part of the connection string.

Comment: Still facing this error:     Failed to connect to data sourceSystem.InvalidOperationException:The'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registererd on local machine

Comment: its working now..by clicking on option of AnyCpu..Thanks a lot for your response..